# Can I access/create InnoDB tables in the database

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website on my server. I have installed CVCRM plugin on that site. I have configured database name, MySql server, and user credentials. When I click on check requirements button in the connection setting page I am getting an error like this " Unable to create InnoDB tables. MySQL InnoDB support is required for CiviCRM but is either not available or not enabled in this MySQL database server ". We installed CiviCRM WP Plugin version 4.1.0. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks & Regards
Surya

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM requires InnoDB support. It sounds like your MySQL server is not currently configured to provide this. If you have control over your MySQL server you should be able to enable this. If you don’t have control talk to your hosting provider to get it enabled.

Best practice is to have a separate database for CiviCRM.

Comment: Hi Graham, Thanks a lot to respond quickly. But I have enabled the InnoDB and configured as the default engine. Still, I am getting the same error. I tried in different servers by creating a separate database, But in all server, i am getting the same issue. I went through file permissions and given 775 for directories and 664 for files but no luck

Comment: I used Heroku server and created a ClearDB, On that server also I got the same error. I chatted with Heroku team and finally they said that this is not a problem with InnoDB, may be a problem with file permissions.